# Continuation of a HTML Form within Django loop

Tags: html, django, forms, django-templates

Is it possible to close, and then re-open/continue a html form on a page? Basically I have a spreadsheet-esk web front pulling out data from a database. However, I was required to split the fields into a left div, and a right div. Reason being they wanted a horizontal scrollbar on the right div because it contains many more fields then the left div (left div field are like static fields with no scrollbar), this is to replicate the look of an existing spreadsheet.

I decided to do this using two for loops within my template. The first loop generates the left hand side of the page, then I close the left div, and the second loop generates the right hand side of the page, then I close the right div.

Because of the way I am doing this, I have a problem where I have numerous form elements before closing the first form.

```
<div left>
   <% for bla in bla %}
       <form id="{{ bla.id }}"><submit>
       <input value="{{ bla.name}}"><input value="{{ bla.number }}">
   {% endfor %}
</div>
<div right>
    {% for bla2 in bla2 %}
       <input value="{{ bla2.address}"><input value="{{ bla2.state }}">
       </form>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Obviously I'm having problems, as when you view the html generated by code similar to above you have many form elements that are not closed until the second div is generated. So my POST data is always the very last record.

What I tried, I gave the form a name and id, which was {{ bla.id }}. I then close the form in the first loop, and put a new  tag in the second loop with the same id and name {{ bla.id }}.

I thought the page would know that this form is a continuation of a previous form but alas it did not work and I can't seem to find a way around it.

Maybe my whole logic is off and I should be generating the whole page differently. Maybe there is a simple solution I am missing...

I hope I explained that well enough.

Any help would be appreciated, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

From the comments, if you wanted to have a submit button for each record, you could still use the markup outlined below, looping over each form tag as a "row". The object names `blah` and `blah2` are somewhat misleading, especially if all of the fields comprise a single model.

If the fields are, in fact, all part of the same model, the for loop would simple move outside of the form tag, instead of within each "column".

Another option, if you don't want to manually output the fields, is to use a model formset to generate multiple instances of a model form. Your markup would be almost identical to what is outlined below, but you would have extra fields for the formset's management forms outside of the formset's loop.

Example:

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div id="left_column">
        <fieldset>
            {% for bla in blah %}
                <input name="name" value="{{ bla.name}}" />
                <input name="number" value="{{ bla.number }}" />
            {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="right_column">
        <fieldset>
            {% for bla2 in blah2 %}
                <input name="address" value="{{ bla2.address}" />
                <input name="state" value="{{ bla2.state }}" />
            {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Each of your form elements will need a name attribute, or you won't find them in the request.POST QueryDict. The form tag must encompass all of the elements you want submitted as part of the POST, unless you're doing the POST via JavaScript and collecting the values via JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Brandon, thanks for your response. So just to clarify your suggestion, I should put the form tag outside the first loop, and end the form after the second loop. I have a submit button for each record, just wondering how the form will know which record is being updated?

Comment: Try: <form action="." method="post" enctype="[whichever enctype you need]"><div id="left_column>all of your form elements for the left column</div><div id="right_column">all of the form elements in the right column</div></form>

If you go with that structure, all of your form elements will be submitted.

Comment: @baz00r Based on your comment about having a submit button for each row. There are a couple of ways you can go about doing that. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks again for your help. Yes the loops are slightly misleading, its all data from the same model so it could have just as easily been two for loops over blah instead of loading all those elements into another instance called blah2 and looping over that, to be honest I don't know why I did it like that. Anyway, with your solution, in my POST data, how do I differentiate between, for example, the ['name'] key from one record as opposed to another. I record. Should I attach the record ID to the end of each name field, in effect making something like ['name1'], ['name2'] etc:

Comment: It depends. If you have a form for each record, you won't need to differentiate, as you're only posting one record at a time. You would need to hand in the primary key, or other way to uniquely identify the record. If you go the formset route, and have one submit button, the formset takes care of differentiating the records for you.

Comment: @svnpenn Weird. No hard feelings :)

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for the help so far. I have got it working. Basically I just went with the single form idea, I'm submitting all the data. However my per record submit button has the value of the unique record ID it relates to, so I am using this in my view to workout which record to update. It seems to work.